# Reaction of Alkyl Halide with Ag2S / Na2S

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, nucleophilic-substitution, silver

What does alkyl halides give on reaction with $\ce{Ag2S / Na2S}$?  In my book, it is given as $\ce{R-S-R}$ but I am not quite sure as alkyl halide react with moist $\ce{Ag2O}$ to gives $\ce{R-OH}$ and thus I am expecting an analogous product.

Comment: RSH is a better nucleophile than ROH